# UDP and TCP listening for massive data

Tags: performance, tcp, gps, udp

Well I'm wondering if you professionals would like to answer my questions about UDP and TCP port listening.

I recently took on a project which is not mine, I'm now in charge of it and this area is just not on my knowledge base. At the time there is a delphi UDP and TCP port program listening to the ports. This ports receive thousands if not more message per second. GPS related data.

My question is what would be the best open source language to do this? By this I mean C++, JAVA, PEARL or similar. That can run on any O.S since at the time the server is Windows its the plan to switch to Ubuntu at some time.

And also if you could direct me to good readings on this topic and examples on the mentioned languages would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are looking for:

- portability between Windows and Linux
- maintainability
- not ultra high performance

Thousand messages per second is not that much. Your programs will be I/O bound anyway.

I would suggest Python. It is well documented and well supported on all important platforms.

Another option would be C++ with boost: This is the high performance option. It will probably take you 2000 times longer to get something to work compared to Python, since Python comes with batteries included and C++ (even with boost) does not.

Java: Half baked thing. Not fast. Not open source. Not easy to deal with.

Pearl: Are you kidding?

But regardless of the programming languages, you need to learn about sockets, UDP and TCP to deal with your problem.